# Filter using IndexOf() returning blank results

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm running a filter on a list that looks like this.

```
if (!(this.state.filter && c.lastName && c.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) == -1)) {
                return true
} else if (!(this.state.filter && c.firstName && c.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) == -1)){
                return true
} else if (!(this.state.filter && name && name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) == -1)){
                return true
}  else if (!(this.state.filter && c.email && c.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) == -1)){
                return true
} else {
                return false
}
```

But, because `null`, `0`, and `''` all match that query, every filter returns everyone who doesn't have either a first name, last name, or email.

I know I could separate this by having separate filter fields for each item, but it seems like there must be a better way to not match the empty string?

Comment: Your use of  the leading `!` means that any failure in the condition will be reversed and accepted. Get rid of that, and change the `.indexOf` comparison to `!= -1`.

Comment: The goal is to return `true` if `c.lastName`, `c.firstName`, `name` (is it correct it's missing `c.`?), or `c.email` contains `this.state.filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that your property is of type string, so instead of

```
... && c.lastName && ...
```

it would need:

```
... && typeof c.lastName === 'string' && ...
```

To condense it all a bit, you could do:

```
return !this.state.filter
        || [c.lastName, c.firstName, name, c.email].some( 
                value => typeof value === 'string' 
                        && value.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.filter) );
```

```js
var test = {
    state: {},
    test: function(c, name) {
        return !this.state.filter
            || [c.lastName, c.firstName, name, c.email].some( 
                    value => typeof value === 'string' 
                            && value.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.filter) );
    }
}

test.state.filter = 'abcd';
var res = test.test({ lastName: 'Mr abc', firstName: 'Helen' }, '');
console.log(res);
res = test.test({ lastName: 'Mr abcd', firstName: 'Helen' }, 'John');
console.log(res);
res = test.test({ lastName: 0, firstName: null }, NaN);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: *"You need to check that your property is not `undefined`..."* Why? That still leaves `0`, `NaN`, `false` and `null` as possibilities that'll throw an error. Just doing `c.lastName` covers them all, as well as the empty string.

Comment: ...though I think you may have the intent of the `this.state.filter` right. I can't tell from the question which direction that should go.

Comment: @squint, agreed on the first point, although a numeric value 1 would then still trigger an error on `toLowerCase`. I changed the test to `typeof`, making sure it is a string. This way it will not try to match something it shouldn't.

Comment: Yeah, good point. A `typeof` test is really what's needed here.

Comment: This was perfect - in the end I also took out first name and last name, as the name (which was just first name plus last name) matched all values.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to return `true` if `c.lastName`, `c.firstName`, `name` (is it correct it's missing `c.`?), or `c.email` contains `this.state.filter`, then you simply do:

```
if (this.state.filter &&
    (c.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1 ||
     c.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1 ||
     name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1 ||
     c.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1
   )) {
    // There's a filter and at least one thing matched
    return true;
} else {
    // There's no filter, or it didn't match anything
    return false;
}
```

If you're literally returning that, no need for the `if`:

```
return (this.state.filter && (
    c.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1 ||
    c.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1 ||
    name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1 ||
    c.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1
));
```

No need to test `c.lastName` and such for truthiness unless they may not be strings.

---

Or alternately, via string concatenation so we're only having to do `toLowerCase().indexOf()` once:

```
return (this.state.filter &&
    (c.lastName + "\t" + c.firstName + "\t" + name + "\t" + c.email).toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(this.state.filter) != -1
);
```

...assuming `this.state.filter` cannot contain a tab.

Comment: maybe better readable: `[c.lastName, c.firstName, name, c.email].join('|').toLowereCase() ...`